# scipy.special.erf raises a runtime warning with 0.j

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy

```
>>> from scipy.special import erf
>>> print (erf(0.j))
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in erf
0j
```

This warning is only printed once (even if I do `scipy.special.errprint(0)`), but I don't understand why it's printed at all.  Really, `0.j` is the same number as `0.` and it has no problem with that one.

I suppose there are two questions:
1) Is there any way to suppress this warning?
2) Is this warning a bug, or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

I (think I) tracked down the error function in the scipy source tree.  It is located in: `scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f` (`subroutine CERROR`).  This function does not raise the warning (It works fine when called from a simple fortran program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off warnings with [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

```
    numpy.seterr(invalid='ignore')
```

---

`0.j` is not the same as `0.`. The former is a complex number, that latter is just a float.

```
>>> type(0.j)
<class 'complex'>
>>> type(0.)
<class 'float'>
```

The complex erf and real erf use different algorithms, e.g.

```
>>> erf(complex(1))
(0.84270079294971512+0j)
>>> erf(1)
0.84270079294971478
```

Since the real erf and complex erf use different algorithms, some warnings in the complex erf will not be present in the real erf. If we check the [Fortran implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f#L2440), we'll find:

```
    SUBROUTINE CERROR(Z,CER)
C   ...
    Z1=Z
C   ...
    CS=Z1
    CR=Z1
    DO 10 K=1,120
        CR=CR*Z1*Z1/(K+0.5D0)
        CS=CS+CR
        IF (CDABS(CR/CS).LT.1.0D-15) GO TO 15
10  CONTINUE
```

In particular, Z = 0 + 0j, so Z1 = 0 + 0j, so CS = CR = 0 + 0j before the loop. At the first iteration of the loop, we get:

- CR ← CR × Z1<sup>2</sup> / (K + 0.5) = 0 + 0j
- CS ← CS + CR = 0 + 0j

and then the condition requires CR/CS, which is a 0/0, which is an invalid floating point operation, and thus the warning.

This is a minor issue which can be "fixed" easily by checking if Z == 0 at the beginning. You could [report a bug](http://www.scipy.org/BugReport) if you find this behavior erratic.

Comment: I understand that they're different numbers as far as python is concerned.  But mathematically, they're not different.  My point was just that if 0. isn't an invalid number, 0.j shouldn't be either.  But, thanks for the way to turn off the warning.

Comment: @mgilson: The problem isn't that 0j is invalid to erf. The invalid warning is raised whenever an invalid floating point operation is encountered during the computation, e.g. 0/0.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Compiling my test program with `-ffpe-trap=invalid` (gfortran) cause the FPE to kill the process on a SIGFPE.  It's still a little weird because using the function `CERF` instead of `CERROR` doesn't cause any problems.  Both claim to return the error function of a complex argument.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't file a bug report asking the scipy devs to use the `CERF` algorithm in `CERROR`?

Comment: @mgilson: CERROR just computes erf, CERF computes its derivative as well, and probably CERF is less accurate. When filing a bug report, better just describe the bug, and let the devs to determine the best solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I filed a bug report.  Ball's in their court now.